# TextView shadow on focused state

Tags: android

I would like to add a shadow to a TextView when it is in state_focused (highlighted with the Dpad).

Haven't been able to figure out how to do this with XML.  There is no "Style State List Resource"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) you find the doc and an example and use onFocusChangeListener for the other parameters.

Comment: I am trying to set the text shadow parameters, android:shadowColor android:shadowDx, android:shadowRadius, android:shadowDy.  StateListDrawable can only set a drawable, not TextView formating parameters.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html fits better to your need.

Comment: A color state list might work for shadowColor but what about the other parameters, they take floats.

Comment: I'm not sure you can use xml for the floats. I suggest you using http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html to handle your float changes.

Comment: I'll mark your response as a correct answer if you edit it to say to use a ColorStateList for shadowColor and onFocusChangeListener for the other parameters.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Turns out you can't use a ColorStateList for shadowColor.  So it all has to be done in Java using onFocusChangeListener.

Comment: @miguel Actually you can, but not out-of-the-box. I've added my solution. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can have a selector of colors for TextView (and others). Just use this solution:

You can extend from the TextView class that you use, and add this:

CTOR:

```
    mDecorator = isInEditMode() ? null : new TextViewDecorator(this, context, attrs, defStyle);
```

drawableStateChanged:

```
@Override
protected void drawableStateChanged() {
    super.drawableStateChanged();
    if (!isInEditMode())
        mDecorator.updateShadowColor();
}
```

Also add a new class "TextViewDecorator" :

```
public class TextViewDecorator {
    private final TextView mTextView;
    private ColorStateList mShadowColors;
    private float mShadowDx;
    private float mShadowDy;
    private float mShadowRadius;

    public TextViewDecorator(final TextView textView, final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs,
            final int defStyle) {
        this.mTextView = textView;
        initShadowsParams(context, attrs, defStyle);
        updateShadowColor();
    }

    private void initShadowsParams(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle) {
        if (attrs != null) {
            final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TextView, defStyle, 0);
            mShadowColors = a.getColorStateList(R.styleable.TextView_shadowColor);
            mShadowDx = a.getDimension(R.styleable.TextView_shadowDx, 0);
            mShadowDy = a.getDimension(R.styleable.TextView_shadowDy, 0);
            mShadowRadius = a.getDimension(R.styleable.TextView_shadowRadius, 0);
            a.recycle();
        }
    }

    public void updateShadowColor() {
        if (mShadowColors == null)
            return;
        mTextView.setShadowLayer(mShadowRadius, mShadowDx, mShadowDy,
                mShadowColors.getColorForState(mTextView.getDrawableState(), 0));
        mTextView.invalidate();
    }
}
```

and attr:

```
<declare-styleable name="TextView">
    <attr name="shadowColor" format="color|reference" />
    <attr name="shadowDx" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="shadowDy" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="shadowRadius" format="dimension" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Note that you should of course change the name of "TextView" to what you use.